# Does Intel Atom support OpenVG?

Tags: openvg, intel-atom

Some time ago, I read some rumors on hardware implementation of OpenVG in Intel Atoms of a "new ganeration". Now I cannot find any evidence. So, is there at least some plans to support OpenVG at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer: Yes.

Announced Intel Atom Z6xx is a SoC (System-on-a-Chip), that includes GMA 600 graphical core. GMA 600 is able to accelerate OpenVG as well as OpenGL. I'm not sure this acceleration makes any sense, but it is supported.